Upgrade to 24.04.01: system freezes, no nvidia drivers listed
After the upgrade, the system became a mess.
Random freezes after several minutes upon startup.
System log shows:
23:09:40 systemd: Failed to start app-gnome-gnome\x2dkeyring\x2dsecrets-3384.scope - Application launched by gnome-session-binary.
23:09:39 (uidsynth): fluidsynth.service: Failed to drop capabilities: Operation not permitted
23:09:39 gdm-session-wor: gkr-pam: unable to locate daemon control file
23:09:29 systemd: Failed to start fluidsynth.service - FluidSynth Daemon.
23:09:29 (uidsynth): fluidsynth.service: Failed to drop capabilities: Operation not permitted
23:09:20 vpnagentd: Function: verify_callback File: ../../vpn/CommonCrypt/Certificates/FileCertificate.cpp Line: 417 Invoked Function: X509_verify_cert Return Code: 0 (0x00000000) Description: ok
23:09:15 kernel: index 2 is out of range for type 'ether_addr [1]'
23:09:15 kernel: UBSAN: array-index-out-of-bounds in /var/lib/dkms/broadcom-sta/6.30.223.271/build/src/wl/sys/wl_linux.c:1935:4
23:09:15 wpa_supplicant: bgscan simple: Failed to enable signal strength monitoring
23:09:09 (uetoothd): src/device.c:set_wake_allowed_complete() Set device flags return status: Invalid Parameters
23:09:09 vpnagentd: Function: getTargetPath File: ../../vpn/Common/Utility/DeviceID.cpp Line: 616 /dev/sda3 is not a link
23:09:09 (uetoothd): sap-server: Operation not permitted (1)
23:09:08 vpnagentd: Function: addNSSStore File: ../../vpn/CommonCrypt/Certificates/CollectiveCertStore.cpp Line: 1887 Invoked Function: CNSSCertStore::CNSSCertStore Return Code: -31457275 (0xFE200005) Description: CERTSTORE_ERROR_NULL_POINTER
23:09:07 systemd: Failed to mount snap-kde\x2dframeworks\x2d5\x2dqt\x2d5\x2d14\x2dcore18-4.mount - Mount unit for kde-frameworks-5-qt-5-14-core18, revision 4.
23:09:07 kernel: /var/lib/snapd/snaps/kde-frameworks-5-qt-5-14-core18_4.snap: Can't lookup blockdev
23:09:07 kernel: ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.HS15._PLD due to previous error (AE_AML_BUFFER_LIMIT) (20230628/psparse-529)

Also strange, no nvidia drivers are listed:
❯ ubuntu-drivers devices
udevadm hwdb is deprecated. Use systemd-hwdb instead.
== /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.2/0000:03:00.0 ==
modalias : pci:v000014E4d000043B1sv00001A3Bsd00002123bc02sc80i00
vendor   : Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries
model    : BCM4352 802.11ac Dual Band Wireless Network Adapter
driver   : broadcom-sta-dkms - distro non-free

I got a GTX 756M.
After uninstalling all nvidia packages and reverting to nouveau, the system started working somewhat more stably, but random freezes still occur inevitably.
This means that the root cause is not with the nvidia drivers.
Anyone know what the cause might be? Should I just revert to 22?
